# How do I write my own realloc for table of structure?

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc, function-definition

I am writing a bigger project, and I have a problem with reallocating the array. Firstly I tried using the function `realloc`, but it leaves memory leaks and errors (the project must be compatible with Valgrind). Then I tried writing my own `realloc`, but it does not work, and I have no idea why. Please help (I am reallocating a table of structures).

```
typedef struct {
    char w[2]; //word
    int v; //value
    int d; //direction
    char b; //binary
}node_t;

int realoc(node_t *huff, int length, int expand_size){
    node_t *temp = malloc((length+expand_size) * sizeof(node_t));
    for(int i=0; i<length ;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
            temp[i].w[j] = huff[i].w[j];
        temp[i].v = huff[i].v;
        temp[i].d = huff[i].d;
        temp[i].b = huff[i].b;
        huff=temp;
    }
    return length+expand_size
}
```

Comment: *but it leaves memory leaks and errors* - So.. maybe it is because you are not using it correctly? In such a case reimplementing it won't help you much.

Comment: What do you think `huff = temp` does? It definitely doesn't update the pointer in the function that calls this. Arguments are passed by value in C

Comment: realloc does not leave any memory leaks. Only **your** code. So do not try to reinvent the wheel, only learn how to use it correctly

Comment: `realloc` has worked perfectly fine for the last 50 years. It is highly unlikely that it has stopped working just when you need it. Perhaps you are not using it correctly. If that's the case, any replacement you are going to write is unlikely to work either. I suggest you show your code *with realloc* (not with your replacement) and ask what you are doing wrong,

Comment: post a new question with your original code that calls realloc

Comment: valgrind saying 'invalid read' etc.. does not mean that realloc did the wrong thing or that there are leaks. Post a new question with your original code

Comment: I will but i have cooldown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The previously dynamically allocated memory pointed to by the pointer `node_t *huff` was not freed.

Also do not name your functions similar to C standard functions. This only confuses readers of the code.

You could just write using the standard C function `realloc` for example

```
node_t *temp = realloc( huff, (length+expand_size) * sizeof(node_t));

if ( temp != NULL ) huff = temp;
```

In this case there is no need to copy data because the function `realloc` itself copies them in the new memory extent.

And the function has to accept the pointer buff by reference indirectly through a pointer to pointer. Otherwise it changes its local parameter buff. And in this case the function should return an integer that reports whether the memory was reallocated successfully. For example

```
int realloc_node( node_t **huff, int length, int expand_size )
{
    node_t *temp = realloc( *huff, (length+expand_size) * sizeof(node_t));

    if ( temp != NULL ) *huff = temp;

    return temp != NULL;
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char w[2]; //word
    int v; //value
    int d; //direction
    char b; //binary
}node_t;

int realloc_node( node_t **huff, int length, int expand_size )
{
    node_t *temp = realloc( *huff, ( length + expand_size ) * sizeof( node_t ) );

    if (temp != NULL) *huff = temp;

    return temp != NULL;
}

int main( void )
{
    int length = 2;

    node_t *huff = malloc( 2 * sizeof( node_t ) );

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        huff[i].w[0] = 'A' + i;
        huff[i].w[1] = 'B' + i;
        huff[i].v = i;
        huff[i].d = i;
        huff[i].b = 'C';
    }

    int expand_size = 2;

    if (realloc_node( &huff, length, expand_size ))
    {
        for (int i = length; i < length + expand_size; i++)
        {
            huff[i].w[0] = 'A' + i;
            huff[i].w[1] = 'B' + i;
            huff[i].v = i;
            huff[i].d = i;
            huff[i].b = 'C' + i;
        }

        length += expand_size;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            printf( "%.2s, %d, %d, %c\n", huff[i].w, huff[i].v, huff[i].d, huff[i].b );
        }
    }

    free( huff );
}
```

The program output is

```
AB, 0, 0, C
BC, 1, 1, C
CD, 2, 2, E
DE, 3, 3, F
```

Comment: I tried doing that and my code is working like a charm but if i check it with valgrind it says that it has more than 10 000 000 errors XD. F.e. "Invalid read of size 1" or "Invalid read of size 4" in lines where realloc occurs. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: @MichałJagodzinski Maybe the passed pointer is incorrect.

Comment: What do you mean incorrect?

Comment: @MichałJagodzinski Maybe it does not point to the initially dynamically allocated memory. Without a minimal demonstration program it is difficult to say.

Comment: I can edit my question and show u all of my program (the most important parts), and maybe then we can find a sollution. Would u be down?

Comment: @MichałJagodzinski Please create a minimal program that demonstrates the problem and include the function I showed in my answer. And do not remove your original code from the question.

Comment: @MichałJagodzinski, ... and ask a *new* question about it.  We frown on major changes to questions that already have answers, and you're proposing basically a complete rip & replace.

Comment: @MichałJagodzinski Though indeed it will be much better if you will ask a new question with the updated function that does not produce a memory leak. Otherwise it will only confuse readers of the question and answers.

Comment: I must have some problems in my program but i have no idea where. Thanks for all the help  <3, i will post once again showing my full code

Answer (score 3):

1. Do not return int only `node_t *`
2. Your function will not work as it does not modify the pointer `huff` so it definitely will lead to a memory leak and invalid pointer access.
3. Your function does not free the previously allocated memory.

Generally speaking the function you wrote is ridiculously bad

```
node_t *node_t_realloc(node_t *huff, size_t newsize)
{
    node_t *temp = realloc(huff, sizeof(*temp) * newsize);
    return temp;
}


int main(void)
{
    node_t *myarray = NULL, *tmp;
    tmp = node_t_realloc(myarray, 1);
    if(tmp) myarray = tmp;
    tmp = node_t_realloc(myarray, 5);
    if(tmp) myarray = tmp;

    free(myarray);
}
```

or if you prefer side-effects:

```
node_t *node_t_realloc(node_t **huff, size_t newsize)
{
    node_t *temp = realloc(*huff, sizeof(*temp) * newsize);
    if(temp) *huff = temp;
    return temp;
}


int main(void)
{
    node_t *myarray = NULL;
    node_t_realloc(&myarray, 1);
    node_t_realloc(&myarray, 5);

    free(myarray);
}
```